# How to come out of iframe and click on Logout button using Webdriver in Java

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

How to come out of iframe and click on Logout button using Webdriver in Java. In my application after performing some actions, my application navigates to iframe, where the webdriver hangs and no error message.

My question is: how do I come out of iframe and click on Logout button to complete the testing of that screen. The below code i have used:

```java
String msg = driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty("CSS_Aggrement_ID"))).getText();
System.out.println(msg);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty("Chk_Agree_ID"))).click();

//Taking Screen shot of the Application
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE); 
FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("./screenshots\\Admin_Module_Users_"+cdate+"
          \\Users\\Exp Fico Addendum screen.jpg"));
Thread.sleep(2000);
System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@@");
driver.findElement(By.id(OR.getProperty("btn_Agree_ID"))).click();
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
Thread.sleep(25000);
System.out.println("Accepted the CREDIT SCORING SERVICES AGREEMENT");

//Logging out the current User
driver.findElement(By.id(OR.getProperty("Logout_ID"))).click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
System.out.println("Logged out of the current User Session.");
```

After using this line also, its not working driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

Please help me on this issue. Help will be appreciated.

Please find the attached HTML Code below:

```html
<form id="aspnetForm" action="ComplianceDashboard.aspx" method="post" 
name="aspnetForm">
<div>
<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/WebResource.axd?d=DgT4Mf0N_YMnhVqqtMJl6ITtOm-
Xk1viHB9Vm8r0uVFocGuJaKgPMl-8ToLUzthqyCSIlNvSxgcjF4L5wyRAEY6vEU1&t=634972693685435569">

<script type="text/javascript" src="/ScriptResource.axd?d= 
PmLhVym6fcJAbF6N8oKcob4OkcKdJuMeNvoZdCAHz4U4Q0qaHtiYfqHyr1IFTdWfhbYGobn9MPMr6kFnB9 
NCRJ8XUGF7hc7hr5Fa6o_syM-7UOboB6ZEADy8dFR74eifqG-tb6YdqC4X7V3nX- 
SyE9XZPya0joJB3T99qw6Fdpgiu9iy0&t=634654365694774574">

<script type="text/javascript" src="ScriptResource.axd?d=q2Vc5B1YFU9pDrTfBWIAKBUF0G6r9_ 
FGzOPwn4eK-8azwI4fzyIv_WP_rep31Ydvk9VVNFMQEhuxeubHjn0RMSnI642H4xejCZIhAwgpRiaoTPs9Lj 
zPGo9Pbz2ibVSsIKYF9oXfLnXFYCpuRJjcJueRcD0LZjsVtDpzSE0TpKi_V_LD0&t=634654365694774574">

<script type="text/javascript" src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=bgA2_TraWwLfOIi- 
qXm4QTzj4qMC_VxvPzBO8gRuZSGXbERvYOP1uk0Vw3SjH4jlyIvjudltqVRS6PhHWpBXBnDo7KbiGQGZHf9
TqtlX7itPC7J1c5rwLOn2HWBIh66aoWtws_HcZR0ZAPIYH7MeNi_Qdo81&t=634477875200920676">

<script type="text/javascript" src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=tKx6MMxl0ajYF54PRVK-
04BaPnmTHKNa2bxIkn-UhnTUIPGaGBWY7qxLLopFN3MIPgMDDwiCGYR-h1Krl-n9ohiSW6jt-
DT7YrgrhYezRyuK_IhEY2L1-PiUT6vG8ccRIqqMThTaV69PPyfeZRA8zXTfAh01&t=634477875200920676">

<script type="text/javascript" src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=Vw_LxcTJZ4e2aO6KnqG-
4O2PoAag3yGa5W1T0ofL5NX7KDlkhimlS_Wt0_XAHTgfqRg6ogQUgJDx8RNpyqmyvBa55iIpriHo6QMea2o
9eUUXCn5NBwxs9qJfg_OXmK-klT6fHACBaUFcabg52amuHdsdmd76OpDUKp1HqwxzWQzb9HYz0&t= 
634477875200920676">

<script type="text/javascript" src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=X6VEPsCRDKU5ndnWNCB_GA_eOTg5P-
vwzpit1O5QyN0wmto3gLjqcao02vgs5YkEgaeaZRUtiFD4IU5l7lBA0dYfQRhBa6sEz-jaTjq7RcT-
cpTew74p7eFmtfTXnpdNnST29vdZ1u3Fj8T85soLEwIi1DM1&t=634477875200920676">

<script type="text/javascript" src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=MFh3Z9sRP-
NTUVYMkO8oDcTGuiWtQ_4r2WJOD8AQeYoL86Rf469SXk7xtfXTXmY_QbbPKniuiWpXk_
EWpAxnh4y6jWeEQUlbEynnvGQB4cD6s-vBEYaPY0eWwW-9A7YYmyJGxWm8dCPBnSjciJEwmfagOyU1&t= 
634477875200920676">

<script type="text/javascript" src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=gReSUwOTlQpuI0-3h-
j3Ol2NpM3WxTx5RCjs_pE4Xfxo9_VDVzxWBqtv3dv78pWPkAU7BmfzzXVWj4JBWAIcHimclLqYXQwSY-
rZBTQWRAHxnSw3XC7BSIU6_m5m811OWyEuJr-ElKv7va1jaKhtN5KJsJNWPYg_IcKO6kDCIOIGCi_s0&t= 
634477875200920676">

<script type="text/javascript" src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=Byfckdz7qpMsf229tFO_ 
6L2a3cWku5BilEmXkVKnd2YlsClU_cL8BaV6IWmH11Id1PDtrf1hs1RpxMpo3v471jt62jwiHdj  
1x3MN4uSMfCMUfADxViV4N6yPT3xkI2gMdO9RGieyZlbNBRS7ya1zhVz8OHF5zUtQM2zUEPgciL0iX0gD0&t=
634477875200920676">

<script type="text/javascript" src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=V1mwbeDStxx0x09xeW5ITfSGm2PxL_
1TS2yXroMYZ_Un2vhIILhVWyjaVnJIwojvLUhj5DpiAgdDP1wuCWBNl7DxzsrevfVMPpZytPrMSnz45g7z
lfl4jPGIctlGUTZ6_GkASPxZdeNVtaldbeUnC3GPNIpqFVtDTHfwg3bpFhhtG0PA0&t=
634477875200920676">

<script type="text/javascript" src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=RmdufLtvsviWg7tt5_ 
mqModADNdon5lXzwoF9k7_KB22W9SGcjXi3If_0ynwBX-0_8cvWk9qGF9DLZvqhbrGpiSck1bJRMk6WMaCr4r 
inoBLvf6Fdbl31A2gF1Mlcyrm65H0HZmxRx0-nzUvmkflo-nqN8fV2brgBaHXyLataCTOCpEf0&t= 
634477875200920676">

<script type="text/javascript">
<table id="TABLE1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width: 100%;  
height: 100%;">

<tbody>
<tr style="height: 10%; width: 100%;">
<tr align="left" valign="top" style="height: 85%">
<td style="width: 10%; height: 80%;">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="18%"   
style="table-layout:auto; background-image: url(../Common/Images/sbtn_bg.gif); 
background-color: transparent;">

<tbody>
<tr>
<tr style="background-color:White;">
<td style="background-image:url(Common/Images/sbtn_bg.gif); background-color:White;">
<div id="ctl00_Menu1_scrollDiv" style="height:198Px; OVERFLOW: auto;">
<table id="table1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"   
align="center" width="90%">

<tbody>
<tr bgcolor="white">
<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF" valign="top">
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" valign="top" style="width: 90%">
<table id="ctl00_Menu1_DlMenu" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="background-  
color:White;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none; width:156px; 
border-collapse:collapse;">

<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
</tr>
<tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="white">
<tr bgcolor="white">
<tr bgcolor="white">
<tr bgcolor="white">
<tr bgcolor="white">
<tr bgcolor="white">
<tr bgcolor="white">
<tr bgcolor="white">
<tr bgcolor="white">
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
</td>
<td valign="top" style="width: 74%; height: 80%;">
<script src="Common/JS/popcalendar.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

<div id="calendar" style="z-index:+999;position:absolute;visibility:hidden;"   
onmouseup="document.all.close.src='~/../Common/Images/Cal/close.gif'" 
onmouseover="document.all.close.src='~/../Common/Images/Cal/close.gif'"  
onclick="bShow=true">

<div id="selectMonth" style="z-index:+999;position:absolute;visibility:hidden;"   
onmouseover="document.all.spanMonth.style.borderColor='#666666';"></div>

<div id="selectYear" style="z-index:+999;position:absolute;visibility:hidden;"   
onmouseover="document.all.spanYear.style.borderColor='#666666';"></div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<table style="height:595px;width:100%;border-width:1px;border-color:Black;border-
style:groove;">

<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top" style="width:50%">
<td align="left" valign="top" style="width:50%">
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<input id="ctl00_MasterPlaceHolder_BtnDummyLoader" type="submit" style="display:none;" 
value="" name="ctl00$MasterPlaceHolder$BtnDummyLoader">
<div id="ctl00_MasterPlaceHolder_PnlLoader" style="display: none; position: fixed; 
z-index: 100001;">
<input id="ctl00_MasterPlaceHolder_BtnDummyAA" type="submit" style="display:none;" 
value="" name="ctl00$MasterPlaceHolder$BtnDummyAA">
<div id="ctl00_MasterPlaceHolder_pnlAAC" style="background-color: rgb(243, 249, 253); 
border-color: rgb(255, 153, 0); border-style: solid; height: 200px; width: 470px; 
display: none; position: fixed; z-index: 100001;">

<input id="ctl00_MasterPlaceHolder_BtnDummyRBPN" type="submit" style="display:none;" 
value="" name="ctl00$MasterPlaceHolder$BtnDummyRBPN">

<div id="ctl00_MasterPlaceHolder_pnlRbpnCon" style="background-color: rgb(243, 249,  
253); border-color: rgb(255, 153, 0); border-style: solid; height: 150px; width: 
450px; display: none; position: fixed; z-index: 100001;">

<div id="MPopLoaderBehavior_backgroundElement" class="modalBackground" style="display: 
none; position: fixed; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 10000;"></div>

<div id="MPopConAABehavior_backgroundElement" class="modalBackground" style="display: 
none; position: fixed; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 10000;"></div>

<div id="MPopConRBPNBehavior_backgroundElement" class="modalBackground" 
style="display: none; position: fixed; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 10000;"></div>

</td>
</tr>
<tr valign="bottom" height="5%">
</tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
</form>
```

Comment: i have posted the code which ever i have written and i can't post the HTML code here. hope you understand.

Comment: Again, you have not given us the complete HTML structure of your code. Your question seems to indicate that the form is inside an iframe, and the logout button is outside of the iframe. If this is the case, it appears that your WebDriver code is somewhat correct, but to really get down to the problem you are experiencing, we need to see the whole entire page structure, along with the element mappings you are using.